# Making a master-detail view with a header bar per item group in a Virtual Treeview (TVirtualStringTree)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, virtualtreeview

I am trying to get a result that looks like this out of TVirtualStringTree:

[image: desired virtualtreeview appearance]

I believe that it might be possible either directly with `TVirtualStringTree` (the main Virtual Treeview control by Mike Lischke), or by subclassing it and modifying the inherited control, or by going to a `TVirtualDrawTree`.

Here is what I can get, and shows the problem that I face:

[image: actual vritualtreeview appearance]

The problem I have is that  I can't seem to get the text for column 0 to take up the entire horizontal area of the virtual treeview control. There is a virtual treeview demo in the Advanced demo showing multiline text that appears to do what I need, but I am unable to figure out how to apply it in combination with the detail columns that I need below the header row (shown as Node,Node,Node in the picture).

Here is what I tried:

- Modify ContentRect.Right in BeforeCellPaint event:
- set `toGridExtensions` on in `TreeOptions.MiscOptions`.

Here is a code sample showing  how I tried to change the contentRect:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1BeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
   level:Integer;
begin
 level := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeLevel(Node);
 if (level=0) then
    Inc( ContentRect.Right, 300);

end;
```

**Update:**

Using the answer accepted below, I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `toAutoSpanColumns` option (in `TreeOptions.AutoOptions`), possibly with `OnGetCellIsEmpty` event (shouldn't be needed if you return text only for the first column).

To get multiline nodes init them with `ivsMultiline` state (in OnInitNode event) or set `vtree.MultiLine[Node] := boolean;`